# Obtain a token from the HTTP service

Tags: http, dig

Help in answering the following, please :)

Obtain a token from the HTTP service described in the ‘_http._tcp’ record on somedomain.net. A simple `GET /` against the host/port described in the ‘_http._tcp’ record will provide the token. Copy and paste the token below.

Comment: What have you tried, I have no idea what you want or what the problem is

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to me. I did figure it out though this was tricky. I started with dig _http._tcp.somedomain.net SRV and this gave me a public IP address along with a port 
```_http._tcp.somedomain.net. 60     IN      SRV     10 10 8080 34.X.X.X.``` then I did a ```telnet 34.X.X.X 80``` and did a ```GET /``` as it said in the instructions.